# what's the difference between output of "ulimit" command and the content of file "/etc/security/limits.conf"?

Tags: linux, shell

I am totally confused by obtaining the limits of open file descriptors in Linux.

which value is correct by them?

`ulimit -n` ======> 65535

but
`vim /etc/security/limits.conf`

- soft    nofile  50000
- hard    nofile  90000

Answer (score 4):

The limits applied in `/etc/security/limits.conf` are applied by the limits authentication module at login if it's part of the PAM configuration. Then the shell gets invoked which can apply it's own limits to the shell.

If you're asking which one is in effect, then it's the result from the `ulimit` call. if it's not invoked with the `-H` option, then it displays the soft limit.

The idea behind the `limits.conf` settings is to have a global place to apply limits for, for example, remote logins

Comment: Does the limitation of file descriptors aim at one process or the whole system?

Comment: The limit is per-process. All the limits obtained from `ulimit` are per-process

Answer (score 2):

Limits for things like file descriptors can be set at the user level, or on a system wide level. `/etc/security/limits.conf` is where you can set user level limits, which might be different limits for each user, or just defaults that apply to all users.  The example you show has a **soft** (~warning) level limit of 50000, but a **hard** (absolute maximum) limit of 90000.

However, a system limit of 65535 might be in place, which would take precedence over the user limit.  I think system limits are set in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, if my memory serves correctly.  You might check there to see if you're being limited by the system.

Also, the `ulimit` command can take switches to specifically show the soft (-Sn) and hard (-Hn) limits for file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I do understand what the file **"/etc/security/limits.conf"** means by your explanation.And I checked the file **"/etc/sysctl.conf"**,but there's no more information about file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

i think this conf is used by all the apps in the system. if you do want to change one particular app, you can try setrlimit() or getrlimt(). man doc dose explain everything.